# Why is a sum of an even and a periodic functions and $f(x)=x$ definitely not even?

Tags: periodic-functions

$f(x)$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}$, not constant and even.
$g(x)$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}$, not constant and  periodic.

Why is $f(x) + g(x) + x$ then not even?

It is known that a sum of an even and an odd functions ($f(x) + x$) is neither odd nor even.

But why does adding a periodic function definitely not turn the result into an even function?

Comment: Why would you expect otherwise?

Comment: I don't know, to be honest. What should've led me to treat this idea as unreasonable right away?

Comment: Periodicity has nothing to do with odd- or evenness. Also, in broad terms, even and odd functions are eigenfunctions of the operator $(Tf)(x) = f(-x)$, and periodic functions are eigenfunctions (with eigenvalue $1$) of the operator $(Pf)(x) = f(x + t)$ for some $t$. Since $T$ and $P$ don't commute, their eigenspaces do not coincide, and the sum of their respective eigenfunctions isn't an eigenfunction of either one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $f(x)+g(x)+x$ was even. Since $f(x)$ is even, this implies $g(x)+x$ is even, i.e., for all $x$,
$$g(x)+x=g(-x)-x$$
or equivalently
$$g(x)-g(-x)=-2x$$
Now let $p>0$ be the period of $g$. Then $g(-p/2)=g(p/2)$, so setting $x=p/2$ above yields
$$p=0$$
a contradiction (note that we did not use the fact that $f$ and $g$ are not constant).

Comment: Thank you! So the contradiction method with an observation that the sum of two even functions is definitely even should be used.

Answer (score 0):

You have it wrong: the sum of an even, an odd, and a periodic function can be even. You can easily see this by choosing $\sin x$ as your odd function and $-\sin x$ as your periodic function.

Comment: I agree, the topic of my question is misleading. I meant the case where the odd function is $f(x)=x$. Thank you for pointing out!

Comment: @alexpetnet: You have it wrong again. You are using $f(x)$ to denote your even function, so you can't define $f(x)=x$ as well.

Comment: Yes, I should've used $h(x)=x$. Thanks.